# Same File Browser with option open four or more different folders

Tags: desktop, mate-desktop

I am using the Linux Mint with Mate 1.12.0. When I opened my File Browser I can press F3 to open an extra pane two different directories at the same time. Is it possible in the same window to see four different locations?

Sometimes I manage many folders and to have two file browser open, each with two folders isn't a good option.

Answer (score 0):

as far as i know more than 2 parallel panes are not possible (at least without tweaking), but you can use as much tabs within one window as you like:
[image]

maybe this is the right place to ask further or suggest "new" features or enhancements: https://github.com/mate-desktop/caja

Comment: Exist a file browser similar to the Apple? Because to web developer this browser is so good!

Comment: i don't know apple or apple-browser so i can't give you further advice, but maybe https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/ would be the right place to ask for alternatives...

Comment: i think especially on MATE 1.12 with the snappy edges your workaround with 2 windows (maybe close the side-pane(s) for more space) is not a bad idea...